# Rancher API: Unauthorized 401: must authenticate

Tags: python, python-3.x, rancher

I'm trying to communicate with rancher API, tried different combinations, getting the same result every time:Unauthorized 401: must authenticate

steps to reproduce:
1)Create Rancher API key and secret
2)Create a simple script that uses them to deploy a test workload.

```
import requests

api_url = "https://myrancherurl.com/v3/project/c-m-qh7tkqn4/jobs"
access_key = "token-zmdpqs"
secret_key = "fr9v6z9xxfqdgmjv2k9z44zvx6mlrandomtoke"
token=access_key+":"+secret_key


# Set the API token
headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer "+token }

# Set the payload for the API request
payload = {
    "name": "my-job",
    "jobConfig": {
        "image": "nginx:latest",
        "command": ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"],
        "restartPolicy": {
            "name": "Never"
        }
    }
}

# Send the API request to create the job
response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers)

# Print the API response
print(response.json())
```

I'm not 100% sure what exaclty is "Project id", so I tried different combinations, results are the same. I have the impression, that additional config has to be done on rancher side, but can't find any info.
Any ideas?

I've tried also using the official python library, but it seems outdated(and also returns the same erro)

Answer (score 0):

Every object in the Rancher API has an id. **Project** is a like a group used to organize various namespaces, and workloads.

There are three types of clients that are used to interact with the Rancher API.

- Management (Used to interact with general objects not tied to any cluster/project)
- Cluster (Used to interact with objects that are tied to a specific cluster)
- Project (Used to interact with objects that are tied to a specific project)

**Sample code:**

`pip install git+https://github.com/rancher/client-python.git@master`

```
import rancher

rancher_url = 'https://rancher.example.com/v3'
rancher_token = 'token-abcde:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
rancher_verify_ssl_certs = True

management_client = rancher.Client(
    url=rancher_url,
    token=rancher_token,
    verify=rancher_verify_ssl_certs
)

clusters_info = management_client.list_cluster(name='leo-downstream')
my_cluster = clusters_info.data[0]
projects_info = management_client.list_project(name='Default')
default_project = projects_info.data[0]
default_project_url = default_project.links['self'] + '/schemas'
default_project_client = rancher.Client(url=default_project_url, token=rancher_token, verify=False)

containers = [
    {
        'name': 'one',
        'image': 'nginx',
    }
]
default_project_client.create_workload(
    name='test-workload-creation',
    namespaceId='default',
    scale=1,
    containers=containers
)
```